# Using master page with jQuery

Tags: asp.net

I have one problem ...

I have a new project When creating a master page(site.master), and when calling another page like (home.aspx) then the page gets error.

This is an error:

Server Error in '/' Application.
Content controls have to be top-level controls in a content page or a nested master page that references a master page.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Content controls have to be top-level controls in a content page or a nested master page that references a master page.
Source Error:
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

This is my master page

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Masterpage.master.cs" 

Inherits="WebApplication2.Masterpage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/Jquery.min1.js"></script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is home.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="home.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.home" MasterPageFile="~/Masterpage.Master"  %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
</head>
   <body>
   <div data-role="page">
   <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
           </div>
   <div data-role="content">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                <li><a href="#" data-role="button" id="btn_group1" data-icon="heart">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-role="button" id="btn_group2" data-icon="star">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-role="button" id="btn_group3" data-icon="star">3</a></li> 
                    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

please help me......
Thanks

Comment: This question isn't related to jQuery so I untagged it. You need to read up on [Master Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.ASPX) as your `Home.aspx` file is wrong - you only need to specify a `head` and `ContentPlaceHolder1` section, no need for the `<html>` declaration here

Answer (score 0):

D'nt use html,body and head tags again in content page.
In home.aspx you have to write your code like this :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="home.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.home" MasterPageFile="~/Masterpage.Master"  %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server" >
    <div data-role="page">
       <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
       </div>
       <div data-role="content">
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                    <li><a href="#" data-role="button" id="btn_group1" data-icon="heart">1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-role="button" id="btn_group2" data-icon="star">2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-role="button" id="btn_group3" data-icon="star">3</a></li> 
                        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:content>
```

use this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.ASPX.

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

In home.aspx that nested from Site you cant use `<head></head> or <body></body>`
you must use `<asp:Content>` that defineded in Site